# Is there way to handle long press url on android?

Tags: java, android, popup

Is there way to check if user long press url in e.g. browser or messages? How to make java code recognize it and do certain actions. I want it to work in background.And display some url preview window like it is in iOS safari.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the question because it will resolve your problem ASAP

Comment: I mean I don't know where to start

Comment: please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask